# Multiple Post Show in Slider with optimization

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

On Sample Page, I have slider on which more than 200 Posts are sliding. each slide have 5 images. I have fetch all data in slider but slider load all images first. that's why my page speed is very slow. So i want optimize way to show it in slider without slow loading.

This is my code as show below: [In this code print one image, but i will have 5 images to load].

```
$my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=property&posts_per_page=-1&order=asc');
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 

        echo '<p>'.the_title().'</p>';

        $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
        if($feat_image!=""){ ?><img src="<?php echo $feat_image;?>" width="200"/><?php } 

endwhile;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

So In loop, there is more than 200 data. this results very slow loading. i just want it fast with slider. that's it.

Comment: not clear what you want

Comment: @RamonMarques, I have edited my question. Hope you can got my point

Comment: "I could not use Ajax on Click call like [load more]" what that means? you want ajax or not? Your problem seems like a design problem. First it's not good to load all posts simultaneously, I would load 10 by 10, with infinite scroll for example. Second, your images for those sliders should be thumbnails, compressed and optimized for web, when you click them you load the full original image.

Comment: `I could not use Ajax on Click call like [load more]` means user of this would not have any interaction device like mouse or keyboard, so user will not able to click load more or scroll.

Comment: He want's to figure out how lazy loading with Flexslider works.

Comment: I think now more clear about the question

Comment: initially sow one image in slider then using ajax append the image one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Lazy load for much Images in Page to Load in View Port.